# In Ruby what is the most correct terminology for files and paths?

Tags: ruby, file, filenames, filepath

Is the following terminology correct?

```
'/path/to/file.txt' # filename: 
'/path/to' # dirname
'file.txt' # basename
```

According to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html) for `File`, these would appear to be canonical, though they differ from Unix, which I believe uses `pathname` in place of `filename`.

I've seen a wide variety of names used to describe these components in the wild, for example; `pathname`, `file_path`, `base_path`, `dir_path`, `root_path` etc.

Note: I'm talking about filesystem paths, not URIs.

Comment: How would you determine if it was "incorrect"?

Comment: @DaveNewton It would be incorrect if there was a more appropriate, accurately descriptive, widely accepted and understood alternative.

Comment: There probably won't be a more appropriate, accurately descriptive, or widely accepted and understood alternative. Programming languages, OS documentation, and people's brains, all use different ways of describing the same things. You'll just have to adapt.

Comment: has my answwer been helpful?

Comment: @majioa Yes thanks, and I've voted it up. I'm going to leave the question open for the time being to see if anyone else answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide some description of names, and paths for *ruby* `File` subsystem. The definitions are the same of the singleton methods of `File` class.

#### Names

[**`::basename`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-basename)

The method `::basename` is used to know the base name of a file, with out without an extension if last is specified:

```
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")          #=> "ruby.rb"
File.basename("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb", ".rb")   #=> "ruby"
```

[**`::extname`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-extname)

The method `::extname` is used to know the extension name of a file, that is the chars after the last dot. See combination examples on how to use it:

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")   #=> ".rb"
File.extname("foo.")            #=> ""
File.extname("test")            #=> ""
File.extname(".profile")        #=> ""
File.extname(".profile.sh")     #=> ".sh"
```

[**`::dirname`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-dirname)

The method `::dirname` is used to know the folder name of a file, for the specified path to it:

```
File.dirname("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb")   #=> "/home/gumby/work"
```

#### Paths

[**`::absolute_path`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-absolute_path)

The method `::absolute_path` is used to know an absolute path to the file, based the specified path, and the current folder if is needed:

```
File.absolute_path("~oracle/bin")       #=> "<relative_path>/~oracle/bin"
File.absolute_path("/oracle/bin")       #=> "/oracle/bin"
```

[**`::expand_path`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path)

The method `::expand_path` as well as the `::absolute_path` is used to know an absolute path to the file, based the specified path, the current folder if is needed, and the base path or a file if is specified:

```
File.expand_path("~oracle/bin")           #=> "/home/oracle/bin"
File.expand_path("ruby", "/usr/bin")      #=> "/usr/bin/ruby"

File.expand_path("../../lib/mygem.rb", __FILE__)
#=> ".../path/to/project/lib/mygem.rb"
```

[**`::realpath`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-realpath)

Just the citate:

> Returns the real (absolute) pathname of pathname in the actual filesystem not containing symlinks or useless dots.

```
realpath(pathname [, dir_string]) → real_pathname
```